How to get Solana Nft collection's data
I am just starting out Solana development and have been exploring the NFTs meta-data. I see there are some services like solscan.io
Here, all of the data for an NFT collection is shown. For example, which marketplaces this collection is traded on, floor prices in different market places, it's holders count etc.
I am trying to find a way of, how can I get all this data? Is there any method in web3.js? How can I fetch this data without interacting with each marketplace's API individually?
I would like that, for a given NFT collection, I get listings in different marketplaces, floor prices in different marketplaces, holder counts, the activity on the collection itself.
I have not tried aything myself as, I lack information on where to find all this data. Just direct me, where I can find all this information.

Solscan is likely using APIs for each marketplace in order to get all of the information. web3.js doesn't contain any special logic for parsing NFTs or marketplaces, only raw on-chain data. The APIs and 3rd party libraries provide the proper decoding of transactions and accounts to get things like "floor prices" and "marketplaces"

I see. I also did some research and yes, I could not find anything that would give me NFTs data for each marketplace so, yea, using third party libraries seems to be the only way
